# How to check if the user's login details are still in the firebase when opening the app

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am trying to check if user's details are still in firebase when opening the app. If so he should move to the main activity else move to the login activity.

```
 if(auth.currentUser != null){

    Handler().postDelayed({
       val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
       startActivity(intent)
       finish()
    }, 3000)
 }else{
    Handler().postDelayed({
       val intent = Intent(this, SignUp::class.java)
       startActivity(intent)
       finish()
 },3000)}
```

Comment: You say "if user's details are still in firebase". Which Firebase service? Firebase auth, Firestore or Realtime Database?

Comment: Firebase auth. If I removed a user in firebase, the app still lets him access the app. I want to ensure that doesn't happen

Comment: SO are you sure you are signed out when you want to be redirected to the SignUp activity? Show us the corresponding code.